# Testing dynamic-content websites with selenium/python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, automated-tests, selenium-grid

What is the right path to learn for testing web pages that have dynamically generated content, for example a survey generator, also there are some elements that hide or become visible in a certain state (e.g. if age > 22 then display a new text area else a warning alert) ...

So what should I learn? what are the requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the selenium webdriver to wait until the element visible by using implicit wait or explicit wait

Answer (score 0):

At first I search elements we can use in the site. 
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Xpath gives us good information about the site you want to test. 
Chrome will help you to get Xpath.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en